# Is it possible for a TIdServerContext to be used more than once at the same time?

Tags: delphi, indy, httpserver

Now I know that on an Indy HTTP Server (`TIdHTTPServer`), the `TIdServerContext` is re-used for multiple requests incoming from a particular client. However, while designing how things work, I need to know whether it is possible that multiple requests could overlap each other using the same context class?

For example, imagine typing a URL in a browser and pressing refresh over and over. What I see happen is multiple context classes get created. However, I'm afraid that somewhere, the same context instance might be used to handle two requests at the same time.

Is it possible for that to happen? Or is it safe to say that one instance will never process multiple requests at the same time? I'm almost sure it's the latter, considering the context is its own thread, but I need to be sure.

Comment: Essentially you are asking if the context can be associated with more than one thread. I think you know the answer to that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Now I know that on an Indy HTTP Server (TIdHTTPServer), the TIdServerContext is re-used for multiple requests incoming from a particular client.

Only if the client and server are using HTTP keep-alives so multiple requests can be sent over a single TCP connection.  Otherwise, the connection is closed after each response.

> However, while designing how things work, I need to know whether it is possible that multiple requests could overlap each other using the same context class?

No.  Indy context objects are created on a per-connection basis, they are run on a single thread at a time, and HTTP 1.1 and earlier requests are processed one at a time per connection (HTTP 2 allows multiple requests in parallel, but Indy does not implement HTTP 2 at this time).

> For example, imagine typing a URL in a browser and pressing refresh over and over. What I see happen is multiple context classes get created

On a refresh, the browser is closing the current connection and creating a new one.  Closing the connection is the only way to cancel a pending request that has not completed yet.

> However, I'm afraid that somewhere, the same context instance might be used to handle two requests at the same time.

That is not possible.

> Is it possible for that to happen?

No.

> Or is it safe to say that one instance will never process multiple requests at the same time?

Yes.  It *may* process multiple requests during its lifetime, but not in parallel.

> I'm almost sure it's the latter, considering the context is its own thread

The context is not a thread. More accurately, the context represents a specific connection, which happens to be serviced by only one thread. Indy can re-use threads (if you assign a thread-pooling scheduler to the server), where a given thread may service multiple contexts during its lifetime.  But Indy does not re-use a context for multiple connections.